# Limit access of a java class to some packages

Tags: java

I have a `Java` class which have some confidential information which I don't want to provide to any unauthorized class.

I want to access this class in some packages (classes from this packages are going to utilize confidential information), So that my secure class should be accessible in these packages.

Is there any way where I can check if caller of method is a authorized class from authorized package or not?

I know public/private/default all things (so please don't ask me to use it), but those are not useful here, because I want a class to be accessible in some packages(not one/same).

Comment: How clumsy can you afford to let it get?  How much effort can you require on the part of your callers?

Comment: @RohitJain -- There actually several ways to handle this, but they require some effort to implement.

Comment: Are you saying that the  actual class definition holds data that you want to secure, or are it's objects carriers for data stored somewhere else?

Comment: Hi Glen, for a simple example- ammm... suppose my class have a method to return a database connection, and I want this method to be called/used only from inside some selected packages. (there are other views too which I want to achieve).

Comment: There may be a way to pull this off with the `doPrivileged` mechanism.

Answer (score 5):

I feel that you are going in the wrong direction. It might be a design problem.

The security requirement is your business logic. You should implement your security policy somehow, not rely on the java language level visibility modifier or caller package names. since if you give your jar to someone, he can anyway get access to your "confidencial" class.

And moreover, a class is a type, something abstract. it should not contain "data". well sure sometimes conf information was written as static variable etc. However if some data is sensitive, it should not be written in class. It could be stored in database or encrypted file and so on. Once a request to the sensitive information comes, you check your implemented security policy, if it is allowed to access those data.

just my 2cents

Comment: isn't there any way in java to secure our .jar/.class files?

Comment: @Patriks yes there is! but the goal is to protect the jar file from de-compilation. Or makes someone reading/understanding your de-compiled classes very hard. for example, http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.htm . however does this suit your case?

Answer (score 2):

The visibility modifiers in Java are not a security tool, but an OO design tool. Whatever you might do, if someone uses your class, it can access any private members of any class using reflection.

If your objects contain confidential information, leave these objects in your secure server.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `Exception` (no need for it to be thrown) and use the `getStackTrace()` to analize the call stack. I always found it ugly, though.

That said, anything that you put in a client machine is vulnerable to that machine; if you have something really confidential protect it in your server; make it available only as a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), implemented by the [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class in Java - it is designed exactly for your purpose.

[Here](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-11-2000/jw-1110-proxy.html) is a how-to.

EDIT : AFAIK, you cannot use the regular Proxy mechanism for static methods, as the proxy and the proxied class must implement a common interface. However, there are more advanced tools, which may help you like [javassist](http://www.jboss.org/javassist). Unfortunately I'm not familiar with it myself.

Comment: Hi kostja, this is useful to me :) thanks, but If my class has methods which are static, can I apply the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to leverage aspectj here.  It's theoretically possible to intercept the call to a given classes' methods based on the current flow scope, and have the aspect throw an exception or something.  I'm no aspectj expert though, but the "cflow" pointcut qualifier would be your most likely bet.  Maybe something like this

! cflow(call(* com.mycom.AllowedClient.*))

I haven't tested this kind of pointcut, but i believe it would work.

You'd probably want compile time weaving in this case though (as opposed to load time weaving).

As a side note, i agree with some of the others that i think this is the wrong approach to take.  You protect data.  You protected function access based on logged in user permissions.  You typically don't protect function calls from other classes.

Comment: Matt you are right, and even I agree to them, but this is not 100% to protect that confidential data, at some % is part of project design, where I want to let only some packages access my some classes. and limit access to some classes from some packages.

Answer (score 0):

Guideline 4-2 / EXTEND-2: Limit the accessibility of packages
Containers may hide implementation code by adding to the package.access security property. This property prevents untrusted classes from other class loaders linking and using reflection on the specified package hierarchy. Care must be taken to ensure that packages cannot be accessed by untrusted contexts before this property has been set.

This example code demonstrates how to append to the package.access security property. Note that it is not thread-safe. This code should generally only appear once in a system.

```java
private static final String PACKAGE_ACCESS_KEY = "package.access";

static {
    String packageAccess = Security.getProperty(PACKAGE_ACCESS_KEY);
    Security.setProperty(PACKAGE_ACCESS_KEY,
                         (packageAccess == null || packageAccess.trim().isEmpty()
                                 ? "" : packageAccess + ",")
                                 + "xx.example.product.implementation.");
}
```