# How to restrict access to package in Eclipse Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, package

Is there a way (built-in or via plugin) to restrict access to a Java package from other packages in Eclipse?

**Example:**

Packages (in same project):

com.my.project.common

com.my.project.serviceV1

com.my.project.serviceV2

Now I want to restrict access to serviceV1 and serviceV2 **from** common. But of course those services should be allowed to access the common package

Comment: How familiar are you with the `public`, `protected`, `private` Java keywords?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon, I think the OP is looking for a way to restrict from certain packages, and I don't think it it's necessarily going to work using package protection. For example, he might want com.my.project.someOtherPackage to be able to access serviceV1. I may be wrong, we'll see how he responds.

Comment: @JeffStorey my point being that if one is familiar with the basics of public/protected/private, one should know that what the OP wants to achieve is basically not possible :)

Comment: It's not possible using built in java constructs, but almost anything is possible from a plugin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit access of a java class to some packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799422/limit-access-of-a-java-class-to-some-packages)

Comment: The problem with packages in Java is, that there exists no possibility to restrict access to classes only in one direction: e.g. you cannot restrict access only from top to down. This is often architecturally desired but cannot be enforced with Java modifiers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: If all you are looking for is simple package level protection that can be achieved using the private/protected/public/default package scopes, then I agree with the comment from @AlexisPigeon - that's the simplest route. Otherwise, I would consider the jdepend solution I proposed below.

No, this is not possible. I recommend looking at [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html). It can produce a report of the package dependencies. You could write a script to parse the output and then fail your build (there are jdepend plugins for maven, ant and gradle) if one of your dependency constraints are violated.